# Updating Chart.js Datasets - Array not re-initializing (Jquery / PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chart.js (v 3.3.2) to display a bar graph (myChart) with a dropdown filter. I have an event listener for my dropdown to update the PHP/SQL query to fetch the correct data - this works perfectly.

But my graph still displays the old data after the update (With disabling cache). The ajax function is POST'ing correctly. Following the chart.js docs on updating the datasets :: [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

I declare `chart, label, data` in my `ajax: success` function's params.

In my `success` function:

```js
success: function (chart, label, data) {
      myChart.data.labels.push(label);              //Push the labels for chart
      myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {  //Push data for each dataset
            dataset.data.push(data); });
                console.log(myChart.data.labels);  // Log new labels
                console.log(myChart.data.datasets);// Log new array
            myChart.update();                      // Update my chart
}
```

I look at the response from my PHP fetch file, and the correct data can be seen in the the inspector. ***But*** when looking at the data in my console log, I am still seeing the old data.

Comment: Please don't just delete questions only to ask them again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update my chart with the filtered database array? (PHP / Chart.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242383/how-do-i-update-my-chart-with-the-filtered-database-array-php-chart-js)

Comment: @hakre I DID NOT DELETE MY QUESTION. It was flagged as a duplicate, to a question that had nothing to do with mine.

Comment: @LeeLenalee unfortunately not, even after disabling the cache - the old data was still presented.

Comment: So you had your question deleted by community decision and then mistreated the vote by posting it again? And you now let other users guess again all the things that has been guessed already yesterday? Is this how you like to treat it?

Comment: First of all it's not a debugging service, therefore logic dictates, you have to double check your intends and do the research on site. If the only research was to learn a duplicate suggestion was not fitting but anything else, it shows very little effort. I have no morale about that, but perhaps it might make you what you just coined, yes. To which you're adding up by showing your expectation that solutions have to be put forward by the community to your advancement. It has not. You're contributions have to be for the advancement of the community, not the other way round.

Comment: @hakre This question was not submitted for 'debugging'. I've done extensive research on chart.js, read through their docs, went through their GitHub and nothing on this. The effort is there. So what you are saying is, that Stack is **not for seeking help?** _I_ must ask the question, and answer my _own_ question to help devs that may have the same issue in the future?  If I spotted the issue, I wouldn't have posted the question. As you can see, I have asked very few questions. This is because I do the research **before** asking.

Comment: I can only give you tips, I'm not your mentor. divide the problem, verify your expectations, e.g. does update work if data changes. then test only the ajax part if the datachanges. bring this together. in it's current form you're asking about many things at once. that is hard to answer. this may appear as if research leads to nothing (my problem is that special, I'm the first one who experience it because all the other code-headz on SO just talk about other stuff) and only useless comments with no traction. Break your problem down and focus on one part first and get it out of the way.

Comment: @hakre I completely understand, and I'm not seeking the mentorship. True, reading over my question it does appear vague, but I want to make sure enough information is given in the question. I will update my code to focus on the exact issue now.

Comment: Also ask the question to yourself what your actual programming question is. What is the part you don't understand? What is the question that would answer that part. What must the answer contain to continue the program. Often tjhis means less information than more (and doing less is harder than doing more, just saying).

Comment: @hakre I've updated my question now, stating the exact problem instead. Did I go about it the correct way?

Comment: At least it's more clear, but you may not like the (my) answer: _"But when looking at the data in my console log, I am still seeing the old data."_ _I_ would say, this is a clear sign the data is cached and the ajax request is unable to fetch the new data. Can you make a post request for ajax? in HTTP there is the mandate that POST request must never be cached.

Comment: And maybe one caveat: can you log the actual `data`  as well, like before you push it into the Chart component? That should really clarify if the Ajax request is receiving the new data and it's a problem with updating the charts component data.

Comment: @hakre you are correct. I logged the data before the ajax, and after and it's return the exact same array. In my networks tab the correct array is displaying. So it is the AJAX request that's not getting the new data

Comment: what? now thats kind of unexpected. if the network tab shows the correct array, like as the response from the server, it means there is no caching, and in my understanding it must mean that the ajax request is receiving the fresh data. I mean that is the XHR request, right? So maybe the way the success method is bound (it looks wrapped per the difference in its parameters) is the culprit, re-using old data, instead of the new data from the request. So neither an AJAX problem, nor a problem of Chartjs, but the glue code in between. (and now you tell me how that is not debugging ^^)

Comment: @hakre I figured it out, I approached what I wanted to do completely wrong. I’ll put the working code up soon for anyone who may be struggling with the same thing.

Comment: Thats great to read. But please make it an answer, don't put it in the question. Thx :)

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the help, and sorry about earlier!

Comment: You're welcome, and also please accept my apologies as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I approached this all wrong. The `select.on.change()` should have been called outside the function, and when executing, call the `showSuccessRate()` function.

Here is the working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#selectTop')
          .on('change',  // When the user changed the select option, run this
            function () { 
              $('#clisuccessrate-chart').remove(); //Remove the chart canvas (because it would have loaded when document ready)
              $('div#clisuccessrate-container').append('<canvas id="clisuccessrate-chart" height="200"></canvas>'); // Add the canvas back into the html
              
              showSuccessRate(); // Call the function to draw the chart
              
          })// end onchange event

   showSuccessRate(); // Make the Bar Chart when document is ready
 
function showSuccessRate(){ // Build Bar Graph
  {var selectedOption = $('#selectTop').children('option:selected').val(); // Get the value of the option, use this value to set limit in PHP SQL Query
    $.ajax("database/cliSuccessFail-filter.php", {data: {topSelect: selectedOption} ,method:'POST', success: function (data) {
        console.log('The selected option value is: ' + selectedOption); // Log the value to check response
        var mx_cli = [];
        var mx_success = [];
        var mx_failure = [];
        var mx_attempts = [];
       // ^ Declare empty array
        for (var i in data) {
          mx_cli.push(data[i].mx_cli);
          mx_success.push(data[i].mx_success);
          mx_failure.push(data[i].mx_failure);
          mx_attempts.push(data[i].mx_attempts);
        };
     // ^ Populate the arrays
      
        var csf_datasets = {
          labels: mx_cli, // Assign label 
          datasets: [{
              backgroundColor: '#007bff',
              borderColor: '#007bff',
              data: mx_success,
              label: 'Successful'
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: '#ced4da',
              borderColor: '#ced4da',
              data: mx_failure,
              label: 'Unsuccessful'
            }
          ]
        };
        var csf_options = {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
        };

        var csf_config = {
          type: 'bar',
          data: csf_datasets, // Bind dataset 
          options: csf_options, // Bind options
        }

        var $cliSuccessRateChart = $('#clisuccessrate-chart'); // Get the canvas ID
        var myChart = new Chart($cliSuccessRateChart, csf_config); // Draw the chart
       
     } }) // END POST
}
}// END FUNCTION showSuccessRate
}); //End document.ready()
```